# Perimeter of a 'trapped' convex set

Tags: convex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, convex-analysis

Consider the following setup: three bounded, 'nice' convex sets $A \subseteq B \subsetneq C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, and three points $x,y,z\in \partial A\cap \partial B\cap \partial C$ (see edit below).  Imagine a triangle inscribed in a circle, with some convex curves between the edges of the triangle and the circle, 'clamped down' at the vertices of the triangle.

Additionally, there is a volume-preserving *affine* map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the perimeter of $f(A)$ and $f(C)$ are less than the perimeter of $A$ and $C$, respectively.

My question is this: is it true that the perimeter of $f(B)$ is smaller than the perimeter of $B$?

This seems true to me intuitively, but I've been wrong about similar things before; the problem I'm having is that the length in an individual 'sector' *can* increase, but this should be offset by the decrease in the other sectors. Any help would be very appreciated!

**EDIT**: As Wlodzimierz points out below, the question is not true in this generality.  However, I would like to add the additional assumption that the points $x,y,z$ are each *extreme points* of *all three sets* $A,B$ and $C$.  This would rule out the class of counterexamples for the original question.

Comment: what role do the points $x,y,z$ play?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! The three common points are actually in the intersection of the boundaries of the convex sets. I edited the question.

Comment: Is $\ \subsetneq\ $ the same as $\ \subset\ $?

Comment: My of my examples features sharp inequalities. A small modification will keep the inequalities intact while all boundary points of all three convex sets can be extreme. Thus the general answer to the question is still NO.

Comment: **Correction**: *One of my ...* (instead of *My of my ...*, and certainly not *My oh my*).

Comment: Hi Wlodzimierz - I don't think I see the modification; 3 triangles share 3 extreme points if and only if they are all the same triangle.  And I don't see an obvious way to perturb your examples to ones which satisfy my assumptions.

Comment: You're right about the triangles :-)  (And I think that I am right about other convex sets).

Comment: Hi Wlodzimierz, you are correct; if you take a circle (set C) with an equilateral triangle (set A) inscribed within it, and let B = one side of the triangle union the longest arc of the circle, then for $\lambda$ less than but close to 1, the affine map which shrinks in the x-direction and stretches in the y-direction will decrease the perimeter of B, but increase the perimeter of A and C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me add the required modification (as a separate "*answer*" to keep each text clean). I could simply replace $\ f\ $ by $\ f(x\ y):= (a\!\cdot\!x\ \,\frac ya)$, where $\ 0<a<3\ $ and $\ a\ $ is very close to $\ 3$. But I prefer to provide a specific example.

Let me repeat that the answer to the **Question** in general is: **NO**.

Let's consider triangles  $A\subset B\subset C$ defined as follows:

- $A\ :=\ \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(2\ 0)\ \,(0\ 6))$
- $B\ :=\ \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(4\ 0)\ \,(0\ 6))$
- $C\ :=\ \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(4\ 0)\ \,(0\ 12))$

Define $f$ as follows:
$$f(x\ y)\ \, :=\ \, (2\!\cdot\! x\ \ \frac y2)$$

The vertices of the image triangles are:

- $f(A)\ =\ \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(4\ 0)\ \,(0\ 3))$
- $f(B)\ =\ \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(8\ 0)\ \,(0\ 3))$
- $f(C)\ =\ \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(8\ 0)\ \,(0\ 6))$

Let $\ \alpha\ \beta\ \gamma\ \alpha'\ \beta'\ \gamma'\ $ be the perimeters of triangles $\ A\ B\ C\ f(A)\ f(B)\ f(C)\ $ respectively. Then

- $\alpha\ =\ 2+6+\sqrt{40}\ >\ 14 > 12\ =\ \alpha'$
- $\beta\ =\ 4+6+\sqrt{52}\ <\ 8+3+\sqrt{73}\ =\ \beta'$
- $\gamma\ =\ 2\cdot\alpha\ >\ 2\cdot\alpha'\ =\ \gamma'$

That's all.

Comment: Good example - thanks!  I realize now that in the situation I'm in, the three common points are all *extreme* points of each set.  This would force their boundaries to 'move in the same direction'.  Is there still no hope with this additional assumption?  I will edit the question to add this in.

Comment: As I've explained in a comment under the Question, the above additional assumption does not make any essential difference. A small modification can have ALL boundary points extreme, while the sharp inequality will stay intact.

Answer (score 3):

The answer in general is: NO.

Let's consider triangles  $A\subset B\subset C$ defined as follows:

- $A := \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(1\ 0)\ \,(0\ 3))$
- $B := \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(2\ 0)\ \,(0\ 3))$
- $C := \triangle((0\ 0)\ \,(2\ 0)\ \,(0\ 6))$

Define $f$ as follows:
$$f(x\ y)\ \, :=\ \, (3\!\cdot\! x\ \ \frac y3)$$

Then the perimeter of $\ f(A)\ $ is the same as of $\ A$, and of $\ f(C)\ $ as of $\ C$, while the perimeter of $\ f(B)\ $ is strictly larger than that of $\ B$.

**REMARK:** *The sharp and not sharp inequalities are not exactly as required in the question but it is easy to fix it (trivial, I may do it later).*

**On the other hand**, this example has the following symmetric feature:

Consider $\ g := f^{-1}\ $ -- the inverse function, $\ g:f(A)\rightarrow A$; also let
$$A' :=f(A)\qquad B':=f(B)\qquad C':=f(C)$$

Function $\ g\ $ is still volume preserving. Also:

the perimeter of $\ g(A')\ $ is the same as of $\ A'$, and of $\ g(C')\ $ as of $\ C'$, while the perimeter of $\ g(B')\ $ is strictly smaller than that of $\ B'$.

Comment: The exact answer is given below. However the present version is nicer, even if it's not exactly in the required format.

Comment: The exact answer is given **below or above**--it's not possible to know around MathOverflow.